# Why Is My Panel Icon Miscolored?

Tags: debian, xfce, gtk

I am using Debian 11 with XFCE and Adwaita theme and Adwaita icons. I am not a fan of the symbolic panel icons, mainly because they are symbolic and the nm-applet icon is not, and it looks strange and inconsistent. So, to address this, I decided to navigate to `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/legacy/` and symbolically link the `audio-volume-muted-symbolic.symbolic.png` icon to `audio-volume-muted.png` icon to have a non-symbolic icon on the panel. This worked, and now I have a non-symbolic icon on the panel for volume.

However, herein lies the problem: the Adwaita icon on the panel is a weird color now. It is a strange orange/yellow/green color, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Please view the attached image - the issue is outlined in red. If you notice, the icon shown in the thumbnail is normally colored (and is also normally colored when viewed in Ristretto).

What I have tried: Creating symlinks from a symbolic icon to a non-symbolic icon, creating my own icon (my own icon was also strangely colored), moving the icon from the legacy folder into the location of the symbolic icon and renaming it

None of the above seem to work, and the icon is still this strange color.

What in the world is going on?

[image: The Issue]

EDIT: Forgive me the oddly dark image, not sure why it is like that. Bottom line: the icon shows normal colors in the thumbnail, but is a strange green/orange/yellow color on the panel